# Copy file to a remote computer in vbscript

Tags: windows, networking, vbscript, wmi, admin

Is there a way to copy a file to a remote computer using vbscript?

For the remote computer I have administrator's username and password, there is no domain in the network. My local user is not an admin on the remote machine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's code on [this page](http://camie.dyndns.org/technical/wmi-0x80070005-correct-pw/) that shows how to connect using authentication without a domain. Watch out for the the ['Force Guest' problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/microsoft.public.windowsxp.security_admin/MY7dz6bBwFs/-MLisxKrefoJ) on Windows XP though.

Comment: That's great, but not what I need. I am able to connect using WMI to that remote machine, but I need to copy a file.

Comment: You could use xcopy or robocopy both of which support UNC paths: as you have admin credentials, you can use the admin shares C$ and D$ (assuming they are not disabled, in which case you will have to create a shared directory to use)